# Batch - WMIC Command output multiple lines add string (Computer Name)

Tags: batch-file, redirect, command, disk, wmic

I am trying to make a batch script which will output as follows for fixed-disk:

Computer Name, Drive Letter, Free Disk Space

the output can be one line in case there is only one drive or multiple-lines if there are more than one drive

now with following command, i am getting the output for a computer, but this does not give the computer name. I need to include computer name because i will run it against multiple computers by a script using for loop.

wmic /node:"%COMPUTERNAME%" LogicalDisk Where DriveType="3" Get DeviceID,FreeSpace

using batch script, i can output computer name, but it only appears above the disk-space lines

```
echo off
for /f %%i in (computers.txt) do (
echo %%i >>outputfile.txt
wmic /node:"%%i" LogicalDisk Where DriveType="3" Get DeviceID,FreeSpace' >>outputfile.txt
)
```

if the computer name is "COMPUTER1" and has 3 drives, this is coming as

```
COMPUTER1
DeviceID  FreeSpace
C:        <free space bytes>
D:        <free space bytes>
E:        <free space bytes>
```

what i want is:

```
ComputerName DeviceID FreeSpace
COMPUTER1    C:       <free space bytes>
COMPUTER1    D:       <free space bytes>
COMPUTER1    E:       <free space bytes>
```

event the column header can be excluded.

i believe this can be done by for loop, but not sure how. anyone can advise, will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to capture `wmic` output by `for`, then you can postprocess every line:

```
echo Computername  DeviceID  FreeSpace
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic /node:"%%i" LogicalDisk Where DriveType^="3" Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^|find ":"') do @echo %%i  %%a
```

Comment: this is just great! thanks a lot. It solves what I needed.

This is the true strength of this community with so many great people!

Comment: did some changes to capture drive size and putting delimiter
    
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ('wmic /node:"%%i" LogicalDisk Where DriveType^="3" Get DeviceID^,Size^,FreeSpace^|find ":"') do @echo %%i~%%a~%%b~%%c >>%OUTPUT_FILE%

Comment: just keep in mind, `wmic` sorts the output "columns" alphabetically. If you want it "DeviceID, Size, FreeSpace", you need `%%a %%c %%b`